# Add a second git remote repository and commit complete project

Tags: git, repository

On a webserver there is an existing project folder already versioned with git. I now want to add a second repository [remote "second"] and initially push the **already versioned** project into the newly added remote repository. How to do this best practice?

Comment: What do you mean by "commit into the remote"?  Do you simply want to clone the whole repository to the remote?  Or do you want to start a new root branch, create a new commit with the current state of the project but without the history, and push that commit to the remote?

Comment: I want to push the complete project - not just the changes into the newly added remote repository. Yes i want to clone the repository to the empty new remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called Repository Mirroring. (Git Mirroring, SVN Mirroring). See more info [here](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/)

Answer (score 1):

*Committing* in git is a completely local operation: you take changes in the staging area and create a commit from them.

What you seem to be looking for is *pushing*:  Select some local branches and transfer all the commits in these branches to a remote repository.  Assuming you have already set up the remote repository and added the remote, all you need to do to push all local branches and tags is

```
git push --all second
```

Comment: thanks. I am using git since a while but must admit I am no git professional. I know of course that git is a decentralized  repository and that commits are only local. 

When i try to push all branches via --all I get the message: 

! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)

Comment: @MischaLeiss: The repository you are pushing to seems to be a non-bare respository.  You shouldn't push to a non-bare repository.  If you want to be able to push to the new repository, use `git init --bare` to set it up as a bare repository (i.e. one without a working tree).  If the new respository is supposed to be non-bare, it might be easier to use `git clone` to create the it from the already existing one, or `git pull` into it.